# Multi-line text border issue with span tag

Tags: html, css, text

I've a header text which has a border around it. A larger text has two lines, but the border breaks. So, I applied the CSS style `box-decoration-break: clone;`. But this separates the text into two different blocks like in the attached screen. Is it possible to display the border completely around the text?

[image]

Need to implement like this:

[image]

HTML like this;

```html
<span class="border-title">
  LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT
</span
>
```

CSS Style applied;

```css
.border-title {
  color: #264755;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #3cadca;
  padding: 10px 20px 5px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add property `display: inline-block;`

```css
.border-title {
 border: 1px solid blue;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 300px;"><span class="border-title">LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT</span></div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `diplsay` in css

Comment: hehe typo ;) fixed.

Comment: Hi @buxbeatz, thanks. This is one solution. Is there any possibility without max-width? Just to know.

Comment: yes, the max-width I applied was only to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the div max-width from @buxbeatz's post you can add 
`display:block;` to your CSS and it should be good to go.

```css
.border-title {
    color: #264755;
    text-transform: uppercase;    
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #3CADCA;    
    padding: 10px 20px 5px;    
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="border-title">LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT LOREM IPSUM DUMMY CONTENT</span>
```

Comment: Hi @Syfer, thank you for your hint. I tried this before, but the problem is, it I've a small heading the border will be in full width. I would like to fit the border with respect to the width of the text. I think max-width is a good solution.

Comment: you can also try `display:inline-block`? with width 100%? It will fit it into the place you have placed it in.

Comment: It also set the border full width. Not respect to the width.

Comment: remove the width of 100% then?